# Concat the second column value if the first column value is same

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I have a query like below and listed output of it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRACKING_NUM,TITLE_OF_DOC_SEC 
FROM some_table  
WHERE  TRACKING_NUM IS NOT NULL;
```

o/p:

```
TRACKING_NUM   TITLE_OF_DOC_SEC
007            Email Flow
007            Test Bug 53306
007            Title 1119
007            Title Test
007            test bug
009            1156
089            Title 21173
098            test Doc Section
```

I want to re write the query so that get an output to be like this:

```
TRACKING_NUM    TITLE_OF_DOC_SEC
007             Email Flow,Test Bug 53306,Title 1119,Title Test,test bug
009             1156
089             Title 21173
098             test Doc Section
```

can anyone help?

Comment: what version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Listagg() in 11g or WM_Concat() in 10g:

```
   SELECT LISTAGG(TITLE_OF_DOC_SEC, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TRACKING_NUM) AS TITLE_OF_DOC_SEC 
     FROM your table
    WHERE....

   SELECT WM_CONCAT(TITLE_OF_DOC_SEC) AS TITLE_OF_DOC_SEC
     FROM your table
    WHERE....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle 11g+, then you can use [`LISTAGG()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm):

```
SELECT TRACKING_NUM,
  LISTAGG(TITLE_OF_DOC_SEC, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TRACKING_NUM) AS TITLE_OF_DOC_SEC 
FROM some_table  
WHERE  TRACKING_NUM IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY TRACKING_NUM;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/edeae/2)

Answer (score 1):

in 11g Listagg is the best option:

```
SQL> select tracking_num,
  2         listagg(title_of_doc_sec,',') within group (order by title_of_doc_sec) title_of_doc_sec
  3    from (select distinct tracking_num , title_of_doc_sec from some_table)
  4   group by tracking_num;

TRA TITLE_OF_DOC_SEC
--- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
007 Email Flow,Test Bug 53306,Title 1119,Title Test,test bug
009 1156
089 Title 21173
098 test Doc Section
```

10g you can use `wm_concat` (but be aware this is not documented):

```
SQL> select tracking_num,
  2         wm_concat(title_of_doc_sec) title_of_doc_sec
  3    from (select distinct tracking_num , title_of_doc_sec from some_table)
  4   group by tracking_num;

TRA TITLE_OF_DOC_SEC
--- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
007 Title Test,test bug,Title 1119,Email Flow,Test Bug 53306
009 1156
089 Title 21173
098 test Doc Section
```

or even the model clause:

```
SQL> with data as (select distinct tracking_num , title_of_doc_sec from some_table)
  2  select tracking_num, title_of_doc_sec
  3    from (select *
  4            from data
  5          model
  6          partition by (tracking_num)
  7          dimension by (row_number() over (partition by tracking_num order by title_of_doc_sec) rn)
  8          measures (title_of_doc_sec t, cast(null as varchar2(4000)) title_of_doc_sec,
  9                    count(*) over (partition by tracking_num) cnt)
 10          rules(
 11            title_of_doc_sec[any] = case when t[cv() - 1 ] is null
 12                                        then t[cv()]
 13                                        else title_of_doc_sec[cv()-1]||', '|| t[cv()]
 14                                      end
 15          ))
 16   where cnt = rn;

TRA TITLE_OF_DOC_SEC
--- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
007 Email Flow, Test Bug 53306, Title 1119, Title Test, test bug
009 1156
089 Title 21173
098 test Doc Section
```

Comment: wm_concat gives out problem..i have used it previously..i believe when the concat string exceeds a limit..it creates some problem..im using 11g ListAgg would be fine option..anyways thanks for helping out man..

Comment: @roshanK yeah wm_concat and even listagg are varchar2's so would have a 4k limit.